# REST Client and foreign characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, special-characters, rest-client

How does one deal with foreign characters in REST Client? Ie.:

```
RestClient.get "http://api.example.com/1.0/items.json;q=æøå"
```

which in Ruby on Rails unfortunately returns:

```
URI::InvalidURIError in MyController#index
bad URI(is not URI?)
```

The URL works fine in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to its [docs](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client):

> If you need to normalize URIs, e.g. to work with International
>   Resource Identifiers (IRIs), use the addressable gem
>   (addressable.rubyforge.org/api/) in your code:
>
> ```
> require 'addressable/uri'
> RestClient.get(Addressable::URI.parse("http://www.詹姆斯.com/").normalize.to_str)
> ```

Or you can try to encode/escape the string beforehand:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-encode